# Switch statement for interface in Java

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I have an interface `FailureReason` and I'd like to create an enum which implements this interface. So I have something like this:

```
public enum RemoveSalonFailureReason implements FailureReason {
    REASON_1, REASON_2;
}
```

Then I'd like to use it in this way:

```
public class SalonManager {

    public String removeSalon(Long salonId) {
        // some code
        FailureReason failureReason = result.getFailureReason();
        switch (failureReason):
            case REASON_1:
                // do sth
                break;
            case REASON_2:
                // do sth
                break;
    }

}
```

But I get an error "Cant convert to integer". So how can I do this? Is it possible to make `FailureReason` enum? Something like `enum FailureReason extends Enum` or `Enum<FailureReason> failureReason = result.getFailureReason()`?

Comment: If `FailureReason` is an interface then it can't be an enum. If it is an enum you can't extend it. You're trying to switch on a variable that the compiler doesn't know is an enum or not so it will complain. Try a cast instead, e.g. `switch((RemoveSalonFailureReason )failureReason)` - of course you'd have to know the type then - which you'd need to know anyways in order to use `REASON_1` etc. in the case statements.

Answer (score 5):

A `case` statement cannot be used here because not all `FailureReason` are `enum`s.

Alternatives:

1. Use a `Map<FailureReason,Thing>`, look it up and do your `Thing`.
2. Use just one `enum`.
3. Make the `enum` do the work - example follows.

Example of `3` -

```
interface FailureReason {

    public void doMyThing();
}

public enum RemoveSalonFailureReason implements FailureReason {
    REASON_1 {
        @Override
        public void doMyThing() {
            System.out.println("You failed!!!");
        }
    },
    REASON_2 {
        @Override
        public void doMyThing() {
            System.out.println("You failed AGAIN!!!");
        }
    };
}
```

Please do not resort to casting.

Comment: What do you call that? An anonymous enum?

Comment: @flkes - It does look a bit like an anonymous class but this is an accepted way of using `enum`s.

Comment: I cannot use third option because there are different ways of reacting on the result, depending on the context of use.

Answer (score 1):

A cast like this should also work.

```
package general;

interface FailureReason {

}

enum RemoveSalonFailureReason implements FailureReason{
    REASON_1, REASON_2;
}

public class BasicEnum {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FailureReason failureReason = RemoveSalonFailureReason.REASON_1;
    switch ((RemoveSalonFailureReason)failureReason){
        case REASON_1:
            System.out.println("Reason 1 is selected");
            break;
        case REASON_2:
            System.out.println("Reason 2 is selected");
            break;
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach would be to use generics:

```
interface FailureReason<CODE> {
    public CODE getCode();
}

enum RemoveSalonFailureReason implements FailureReason<RemoveSalonFailureReason> {
    REASON_1, REASON_2;

    public RemoveSalonFailureReason getCode() {
        return this;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FailureReason<RemoveSalonFailureReason> failureReason = RemoveSalonFailureReason.REASON_1;
    switch (failureReason.getCode()){
        case REASON_1:
            System.out.println("Reason 1 is selected");
            break;
        case REASON_2:
            System.out.println("Reason 2 is selected");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know, is CODE a special keyword that I don't know of? Because the convention is to use T for types in generics. And any advantage of using generics over a normal interface (if you check my answer)? Cheers

Comment: No CODE isn't special, it's just more descriptive than T. Generics in this instance afford better re-use - you can reuse FailureReason without connecting that code to the Salon and without changing the FailureReason interface.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just add a getter in the interface;

```
RemoveSalonFailureReason getSalonFailureReason();
```

And in your RemoveSalonFailureReason  you implement the getter like

```
RemoveSalonFailureReason getSalonFailureReason(){
  return this;
}
```

And in your removeSalon method you can do

```
public String removeSalon(Long salonId) {
    // some code
    FailureReason failureReason = result.getFailureReason();
    switch (failureReason.getSalonFailureReason()):
        case REASON_1:
            // do sth
            break;
        case REASON_2:
            // do sth
            break;
}
```